# CXF Header element with String

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm trying to construct a simple header element (i.e. contextID) with org.apache.cxf.headers.Header

The XML representation should be like:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <contextID>someString</contextID>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I was trying like this in an interceptor:

```
String contextID = "someString";
List<Header> headers = message.getHeaders();
//this could be possibly wrong
Header contextIdHeader = new Header(new QName(CORE_NAMESPACE, "contextID"), contextID);
headers.add(contextIdHeader);
message.put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
```

But I'm getting an exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element

I suppose, the construction of the Header element is wrong.
What would be the correct way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

the Header element has to be created like this

```
Header contextIdHeader = new Header(new QName(CORE_NAMESPACE, "contextID"), contextID, new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
```